# how to decrease executing select query time

Tags: mysql

decreasing running time (select query executing time)
even query is not working
it is reducing code line
there are 80 tables

```
select 
     (ant_return_loss_pass='pass')+(ant_cross_isolation_pass='pass') as pass_count,
     (ant_return_loss_pass='fail')+(ant_cross_isolation_pass='fail') as fail_count,
     (ant_return_loss_pass='')    +(ant_cross_isolation_pass='') as blank_count
from 
(
  select A.serial_no,
         A.pass_fail as ant_return_loss_pass    
  from ant_return_loss A,
  (                                
      select max(register_date) as date
        from ant_return_loss 
        where 1=1
          and serial_no >= '184500074' 
          and serial_no <= '184500076' 
        group by serial_no
  ) B                                 
  where 1 = 1                     
    and A.register_date = B.date     
)AA
,(
  select A.serial_no,
         A.pass_fail as ant_cross_isolation_pass    
  from ant_cross_isolation A,
  (                                
      select  max(register_date) as date
        from ant_cross_isolation 
        where 1=1
          and serial_no >= '184500074' 
          and serial_no <= '184500076' 
        group by serial_no
  ) B                                 
  where 1 = 1                     
    and A.register_date = B.date     
)BB
where 1=1
  and AA.serial_no = BB.serial_no
```

not working or working 600 sec

Comment: What version of MySQL? Can you provide sample data? and expected results (based on the sample data)?

Answer (score 1):

The query below uses explicit join syntax and case expressions to make you query easier to understand:

```
SELECT
    COUNT( CASE WHEN ant_return_loss_pass = 'pass' AND
                     ant_cross_isolation_pass = 'pass' THEN 1 END ) AS pass_count
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN ant_return_loss_pass = 'fail' AND
                     ant_cross_isolation_pass = 'fail' THEN 1 END ) AS fail_count
  , COUNT( CASE WHEN ant_return_loss_pass = '' AND
                     ant_cross_isolation_pass = '' THEN 1 END )     AS blank_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        A.serial_no
      , A.pass_fail AS ant_return_loss_pass
    FROM ant_return_loss A
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX( register_date ) AS date
            FROM ant_return_loss
            WHERE serial_no >= '184500074'
            AND serial_no <= '184500076'
            GROUP BY serial_no
        ) B ON A.register_date = B.date
    ) AA
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            A.serial_no
          , A.pass_fail AS ant_cross_isolation_pass
        FROM ant_cross_isolation A
        INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  MAX( register_date ) AS date
                FROM ant_cross_isolation
                WHERE serial_no >= '184500074'
                AND serial_no <= '184500076'
                GROUP BY serial_no
            ) B ON A.register_date = B.date
    ) BB ON AA.serial_no = BB.serial_no
```

To examine if this can be improved for performance however requires access to your database. For example do you indexes for `ant_return_loss.serial_no` or `ant_cross_isolation.serial_no` these will aid the where clauses of the subqueries.

Have you run any explain plans on the query? see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Note to avoid long running time you can use explain on separated portions of the overall query, look for indexes that may assist: e.g.

```
            explain
            SELECT MAX( register_date ) AS date
            FROM ant_return_loss
            WHERE serial_no >= '184500074'
            AND serial_no <= '184500076'
            GROUP BY serial_no
```

then:

```
    explain
    SELECT
        A.serial_no
      , A.pass_fail AS ant_return_loss_pass
    FROM ant_return_loss A
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX( register_date ) AS date
            FROM ant_return_loss
            WHERE serial_no >= '184500074'
            AND serial_no <= '184500076'
            GROUP BY serial_no
        ) B ON A.register_date = B.date
```

until you have examined all portions for way to improve performance.

Comment: well it doesn't work when there are tables over 8 ;( anyway thnx

Comment: what does that mean? what does not work? what is "tables over 8"? is that 8 tables? if the query you presented in the question is not the true query, how can anyone help on a query they have not seen?

Comment: Have you attempted to examine any explain plans?